# How to access multiple services deployed (Spring boot app) in google Kubernetes?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I created 2 simple spring boot application and deployed in Google Kubernetes using a docker container by referring this link :
[Deploy spring boot in Kubernetes](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-springboot-kubernetes/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#1)

Now when I run `kubectl get services` i can see 2 services(Spring boot applications) listed!

I understand that using expose I can reserve a static IP for the services! But What I need is ** I need to access two services using Single IP** (Similar to routing) so that end-user need only be known about one IP address for the multiservices! How could I achieve that? I am very new to this! Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GCE Ingress resource so that both services are used as backends.

As mentioned in Patrick's comment above, convert both services to type: NodePort instead of LB. Verify that a node port was allocated.

`kubectl get service web`

and then create ingress with 2 host paths.

The following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) will help you get started:

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to access your services publicly, using the same IP address, would be to use the `ingress-controller` and `Ingress` resource. This will allow you to use dns based hostnames and/or path matching to access each service individually.

I have an easy to use starter repository that I recommend you use to get started. Simply run the following commands:

Install the ingress-controller:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mateothegreat/k8-byexamples-ingress-controller
$ cd k8-byexamples-ingress-controller
$ git submodule update --init

$ make install LOADBALANCER_IP=<your static ip here>
```

Create your `Ingress` resource:

```
$ make issue HOST=<your dns hostname> SERVICE_NAME=<your service> SERVICE_PORT=<the service port>
```

You can repeat this last step as many times as you need. For additional information you can go to https://github.com/mateothegreat/k8-byexamples-ingress-controller.

Comment: LOADBALANCER_IP=<your static ip here>  here i should give the static IP right? but i have 2 spring boot app as services and each have static IPs which should i privide? the application behaviour is like REST API. And i only have IP no DNS name, so what should i give in HOST= "?"

Comment: Ok, in that case, just set the type of your services to be `type: LoadBalancer`

Comment: `kubectl expose deployment hello-java-1 --type=LoadBalancer` `kubectl expose deployment hello-java-2 --type=LoadBalancer` i exposed the deployment as Loadbalancer. But how could i then route  requests to both services using a single IP address?

Comment: You can use a single service that has multiple ports. Then you can make sure your two deployment pods have the same labels as the Service and you will be able to hit your services individually by the corresponding port.

Comment: So we could not access two services like `<IP ADDRESS>/service1/` and `<IP ADDRESS>/service2/`

Comment: No.. because a `Service` has no notion of your url path. That is what an `Ingress` does.

Comment: So how could i achieve this using ingress?

Comment: Please refer to my original reply. This explains it simply for you. Instead of using a hostname, ignore that part, and just use your ip address/path123 when accessing your service.

Comment: As i mentioned above i exposed the 2 deployements as Loadbalancer, so will your solution works in this case also?

Comment: Change both services to 'type: NodePort' instead of LoadBalancer (kubectl edit svc [service name]), then you can configure using an ingress resource using a single IP as yomateo mentioned. You can't use 2 separate resources and assign them both a single static IP, GCP won't allow it